# Specific css setting for IE only

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have the following setting and only want to have this setting for IE only.
Is there the way to do so

```
.login-space {
    padding-right: 30px;margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Thanks
K

Answer (score 0):

One solution is create a style sheet for only IE and put that selector in it and add the style sheet in head section like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

More detail [Here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)